# How to get file name of directory and written in button or label?

Tags: vb.net, directory, filenames

How can I find the file name of a directory?

I would like to customize a label or button.

Example: LigaBBVA.jpg then on the button or the label, LigaBBVA will also written without the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System.IO.Path` class and it's method [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim sampleImgPath = "C:\Images\Liga BBVA.jpg"
Dim nameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sampleImgPath) ' Liga BBVA
```

> How can i get  the directory name of a given directory-path?

Then you need to use [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: how the coding to find the file name in the directory? then written on the button or label. so I don't need to write C: \ images \ League BBVA.jpg but C: \ images

Thanks before

Comment: @Kalasnikov: You can use Path.GetDirectoryName . I've edited my answer.